# In Amazon ElastiCache, how to set up the number of nodes?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elasticache

I've created a cluster with disabled sharding. I see 3 nodes were created: one primary and 2 replicas. The total number of hours for November was 2,160 which cost me a lot.

I don't need 2 replicas, one would be enough. But I can't find a way to decrease this number. The type of instance is cache.t4g.small.

Answer (score 1):

AWS provides [Changing the number of replicas](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/red-ug/increase-decrease-replica-count.html) guide for Elasticache in their documentation.

There are two options - using `awscli` or using ElastiCache API.
Both are described in the documentation.

For the AWS CLI the command to change number of replicas is:

```
aws elasticache decrease-replica-count
    --replication-group-id YOUR_REPLICATION_GROUP_ID \
    --new-replica-count 1 \
    --apply-immediately
```

Note that `--apply-immediately` may result in a short downtime - test that before applying on production environment.

EDIT:
Thanks to @mimic finding - There's also a way to [decrease number of replicas](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/red-ug/decrease-replica-count.html) via AWS Console.
The docs mention decreasing but increasing might work as well - I haven't tested that and cannot say for sure, but if I had an opportunity, I would try that and improve the answer in the future.

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to do it via AWS Console? I'm really struggling with other methods.

Comment: No, unfortunately that's not possible with AWS Console. Yet it should be pretty simple with AWS CLI as long as you have it configured correctly - there are guides for that.

Comment: I found here described how to do it via console: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/red-ug/decrease-replica-count.html The problem is they use different terms so it was pretty confusing to find what was described there.

Comment: Good find, I will update the post with the link.